# How to properly encode link to JSON?

Tags: php, json

**Can someone please help me in encoding a link to JSON syntax to a php string variable?**
The url to encode (link contains hungarian caracters like é):

```
<a href='http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/kapcsolati-kerdoiv/?partner_id=100'>Kérdőív kitöltése</a>
```

It is used with the following php code:

```
$user_survey='"\u003ca href=\"http://www.szerelmifajdalomklinika.hu/kapcsolati-kerdoiv/?partner_id=100\"\u003eKérdőív kitöltése\u003c/a\u003e"';

echo json_encode(array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
    'partner_id' => mysql_insert_id(),
    'partner_nickname' => $partner_nickname,
    'partner_description' => $partner_description,
    'real_partner_id' => $real_partner_id,
    'partner_survey' => $user_survey
));

?>
```

It feeds a table content somewhere else. This runs incorrecly, as the link, or indeed any text does not appear from the partner survey part.

Note, that the code above works with simple strings, for example `$partner_survey="test";` or `$partner_survey="test with some hun chars: ééóóúúűű";` runs correctly.

The following links were used in generating and verifying the encode:
http://edtracks.com/toolkit/decoder-encoder-json-html-url/,

http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Could you post the current output of the code? It's not clear what you mean by "any text does not appear from the partner survey part"

Comment: It feeds to a table cell. It is currently protected with a login.
The symptom is there is "" in the cell. Not a broken link, an empty string.

Comment: But what is the output of this PHP code? Does it contain the text you expect? Why do you think it is the code that is generating it that is at fault, not the code that is decoding it and displaying the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON requires strings to be UTF8-encoded. I personally use these functions:

```
function getjson($json) {
    $j = json_decode($json,true);
    if( !$j) $j = Array();
    array_walk_recursive($j,function(&$a) {if(is_string($a)) $a = utf8_decode($a);});
    return $j;
}
function setjson($json) {
    array_walk_recursive($json,function(&$a) {if(is_string($a)) $a = utf8_encode($a);});
    $j = json_encode($json);
    return $j;
}
```

Although you should note that these deal very specifically with JSON-encoded arrays. They'll work for this particular case, but keep that in mind for more general use.

Side-note: You can establish whether or not UTF8 is the problem as follows:

```
// after attempting to json_encode data:
if( json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_UTF8) echo "ERROR: Invalid encoding";
```

Comment: Please don't treat `utf8_encode`/`utf8_decode` as some kind of magic bullet. As noted on [this comment in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php#104907) "Please note that utf8_decode simply converts a string encoded in UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1. A more appropriate name for it would be utf8_to_iso88591. If your text is already encoded in ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function. If you don't want to use ISO-8859-1, you do not need this function."

Comment: It was about a missed doctype declaration, so something along these lines. Thanks for the help.